# Install Ubuntu 22.10 on the computer with UFS（Universal Flash Storage） showing the error "UUID=xxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell. "

Tags: boot, grub2, mount, ufs

I fail to install Ubuntu 22.10 on my computer with UFS.

My system (Ubuntu 22.10) doesn't boot and show the error "UUID does not exist".

For "ls /dev" we can see there is no "dev/sdbx" thus no hard driver found.

Is Ubuntu 22.10 support install on the computer with UFS?

How can I repair my Ubuntu installation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the modules for booting off Universal Flash Storage (UFS).

1. Boot from your Ubuntu installation USB.
2. Mount the root partition of your Ubuntu installation to `/mnt`.
3. Open a terminal from `/mnt`.
4. Type: 
   `sudo mount --bind /dev "$PWD/dev"`
   `sudo mount --bind /proc "$PWD/proc"`
   `sudo mount --bind /sys "$PWD/sys"`
5. Type: 
   `sudo chroot "$PWD" /bin/bash --login`
6. Type: 
   `echo "ufshcd" >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules`
   `echo "ufshcd-pci" >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules`
7. Type: 
   `update-initramfs -u -k all`
   `exit`
8. Restart your computer and it should boot from your Ubuntu installation on the Universal Flash Storage (UFS).